# Do-while loop does not end?

Tags: c++, function, do-while

I have the weirdest problem! I need to make a program where the user has to input a 10-digit number. So I check the input with a do-while loop:

```
do
{
    cout<<"Enter a 10-digit number: "<<endl;
    cin>>number;
} 
while (numberOfDigits(number) != 10);
```

Here is the numberOfDigits function:

```
    int numberOfDigits(int num)
    {
        int d = 0;

        while (num > 0)
        {
            num /= 10;
            d++;
        }

        return d;
    }
```

So when I enter a number less than 10, it loops and goes to the start (telling me to input a 10-digit number again). However, when I input a number with more than 10 digits, an infinite loop occurs, and the console doesn't stop printing "Enter a 10-digit number: "... Any ideas?

Comment: try changing int to long long

Comment: `int` is usually 32 bits wide; a 32-bit (signed) integer can only values up to 2**31, or just over 2 billion, which is exactly 10 digits already. Anything more than that doesn't fit into the int, and `cin` enters an error state where it can't read anything else (the same would happen if you typed, e.g. "cat" instead of a number). The *safe* way to validate input is to read everything as a string, then check it, then convert it to the final type (`int`, etc.) if the validation passed.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you are going past the max range of a int. If you are typing a number in that is higher then `2,147,483,647` which is extremely likely considering you need 10 numbers. Try using a long long.

```
int numberOfDigits(long long num)
{
    long long d = 0;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        num /= 10;
        d++;
    }

    return d;
}
```

I just tried it and it works fine for me. Full program I used to test:

```
using namespace std;

int numberOfDigits(long long num)
{
    long long d = 0;

    while (num > 0)
    {
        num /= 10;
        d++;
    }

    return d;
}

int main()
{
    long long number = 0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter a 10-digit number: "<<endl;
        cin>>number;
    } 
    while (numberOfDigits(number) != 10);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @Grice, he's entering 10 *digits*, so any 10 digit number that starts with a 3 for example would overflow an int.

Comment: yeah, it does work when I enter a number that starts with 1 or 2 most of the time, but for a larger values it crashes. I changed it to long long and now it works fine. Didn't think about range of types... Thanks guys!

Comment: @aquinas My mistake, the OP's statement `when I input a number bigger than or equal to 10` led me to assume he was entering a literal `10` as the number.

Comment: yeah, my bad, I'll change it now

Answer (score 0):

If you changed

while (numberOfDigits(number) != 10)

to

while (numberOfDigits(number) <= 10)

this way it would continue the do-while loop till the user had selected a number that is less that or equal to.